# Invite Friends through FB for own Application in Ios

Tags: iphone, facebook-graph-api

I am developing an app in iPhone, i need to invite friends to join my application through sending message on FB using graph API, i also want to that when user hit invite friends from FB then my app show dialog box which is actually FB dialog box in which all his friends are shown and user can choose friends on his wish to send message. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by using frictionless request as below

```
 NSString *to =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[[[FriendUIDArray
 objectAtIndex:index]
                                                  objectForKey:@"uid"] intValue]];

 FBFrictionlessRecipientCache *friendCache =
 [[FBFrictionlessRecipientCache alloc] init]; [friendCache
 prefetchAndCacheForSession:nil];


 NSMutableDictionary* params =   [NSMutableDictionary
 dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                  to, @"to",
                                  nil];

 [FBWebDialogs presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:nil
        message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"I’m using Nightup to find great party's 
        around me."] title:nil  parameters:params handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result,
        NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error)
        {
                                                   if (error) {
                                                       // Case A: Error launching the dialog or sending request.
                                                       NSLog(@"Error sending request.");
                                                   } else {
                                                       if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {
                                                           // Case B: User clicked the "x" icon
                                                           NSLog(@"User canceled request.");
                                                       } else {
                                                           NSLog(@"Request Sent.");
                                                       }
         }}

        friendCache:friendCache];
```

If you dont have Uid of specific friend to whom you want to invite then follow this method which allow you to select friend on dialog.

```
NSMutableDictionary* params =   [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:nil]; 
[FBWebDialogs presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:nil
              message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"I just smashed %d friends! Can you beat it?", nScore]
              title:nil
              parameters:params
              handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
                  if (error) {
                      // Case A: Error launching the dialog or sending request.
                      NSLog(@"Error sending request.");
                  } else {
                      if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {
                          // Case B: User clicked the "x" icon
                          NSLog(@"User canceled request.");
                      } else {
                          NSLog(@"Request Sent.");
                  }
}}];
```

You can find more details [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-games/requests/)

Answer (score -1):

Use @"facebook.events.invite" method to invite your friend from iPhone

e.g

```
        params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:facebookEventString,@"eid",udidsString,@"uids",nil];
        [[FBRequest requestWithDelegate:self] call:@"facebook.events.invite" params:params];
```

Comment: i already knew this idea, but this is not which i want, coz i need FB dialog box in which user select specific his friends.